# JS Function that finds the smallest number out of 3 given by the user and then writes it out next to the submit box

Tags: javascript

Here is my form:

```html
<form>
  <label for="number1"> First number</label>
  <input type="number" id="number1" value=""><br /><br />

  <label for="number2"> Second number</label>
  <input type="number" id="number2" value=""><br /><br />

  <label for="number3"> Third number</label>
  <input type="number" id="number3" value=""><br /><br />
  
  <input type="button" class="button" value="The smallest number is" onclick="minimal()">
  <p id="result"></p>
</form>
```

I'm trying to write a JS function that finds the lowest number out of the three and writes it out in the <p id="result" element. I know about Math.min() however I don't know how I'd go about structuring the function, when I tried I got an "Cannot read property 'value' of null" error

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. _Show us_ your actual attempt, even if it throws errors.

Comment: Can you include the function code for `minimal()`, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function minimal() {
  const val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number1").value);
  const val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number2").value);
  const val3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number3").value);
  const res = document.getElementById("result");
  const min = Math.min(val1, val2, val3);
  res.innerText = min;
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="number" id="number1" value=""><label for="number1"> First number</label><br/><br/>
<input type="number" id="number2" value=""><label for="number2"> Second number</label><br/><br/>
<input type="number" id="number3" value=""><label for="number3"> Third number</label><br/><br/>
<input type="button" class="button" value="The smallest number is" onclick="minimal()"><p id="result"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow some steps to get the work done.

- Fetch the input
- convert it into `Number` (as it is in `String`).
- Get the minimum of all three using `Math.min` function.
- Set the result.

That's it

```js
const first = document.querySelector("#number1");
const second = document.querySelector("#number2");
const third = document.querySelector("#number3");
const button = document.querySelector(".button")
const result = document.querySelector("#result");

function minimal() {
  const fno = parseInt(first.value);
  const sno = parseInt(second.value);
  const tno = parseInt(third.value);

  result.textContent = Math.min(fno, sno, tno);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="number1"> First number</label>
  <input type="number" id="number1" value=""><br /><br />

  <label for="number2"> Second number</label>
  <input type="number" id="number2" value=""><br /><br />

  <label for="number3"> Third number</label>
  <input type="number" id="number3" value=""><br /><br />
  <input type="button" class="button" value="The smallest number is" onclick="minimal()">
  <p id="result"></p>
</form>
```